# Why can't I show CJK characters normally in nginx?

Tags: nginx, cjk

Environment: Windows 10 + nginx/1.8.0. The files in the `mysql` directory are all in UTF-8 encoding, and all HTML files in `mysql` contain    `<meta charset="utf-8" />`.

My configuration file for file *nginx.conf*:

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;
        charset gbk,utf-8;
        source_charset gbk,utf-8;
        autoindex on;
        location / {
            root   d:/mydoc/build/html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
            charset gbk,utf-8;
            source_charset gbk,utf-8;
        }
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

I start my nginx server and open the `mysql` directory in Firefox:

[image]

All CJK characters are shown correctly. Now to click the third third title----`mysql日志.html`:

[image]

Display file *error.log* to check what happened:

```
2020/12/05 22:41:19 [error] 11252#11076: *8 CreateFile() "d:/mydoc/build/html/mysql/mysql日志.html" failed
(2: The system cannot find the file specified),
client: 127.0.0.1, server: localhost, request:
"GET /mysql/mysql%C8%D5%D6%BE.html HTTP/1.1", host: "127.0.0.1", referrer: "http://127.0.0.1/mysql/"
```

Input `http://127.0.0.1/mysql/mysql日志.html` in my Firefox and click. All CJK characters are shown correctly.

[image]

How do I solve the issue that it jump into a webpage containing garbled CJK characters when to click title in `127.0.0.1/mysql`?

It is verified that for same directory and files CJK character can shown correctly in *nginx + Linux* instead of *nginx + Windows*.

Answer (score 0):

Following the [alibabacloud guide](https://topic.alibabacloud.com/a/how-to-get-nginx-to-support-chinese-filename_8_8_10157039.html), my best guess is that you should use only `charset utf-8` and you should also check that all filenames are in UTF-8 format or convert to UTF-8 otherwise (only filenames, not the content).

Comment: It talks on  linux+nginx, what i talk is on windows+nginx,it is no use.

Comment: Ok so you should find the equivalent tools in windows, if you don't have a linux machine. Did you check the filenames format?

Comment: All files and directory are created on linux and both filename and content are in utf-8,the issue now is that all of them can show properly on linux+nginx instead of window10+nginx.

Comment: This is great progress and now it sounds like there is a bug in nginx for windows. Check if you are using the same version for both linux and windows. And try to use the latest nginx ver on windows, and if the problem is reproduced open a bug to the nginx team: https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/

Comment: They are same version,It is no use to set chcp 936 or 65001 to solve the issue.

Comment: nginx for windows is considered as beta https://nginx.org/en/docs/windows.html. So it's probably a bug